# Computing the coordinate representation of a vector field

Tags: differential-topology

Let $V=x\frac{∂}{∂x}+y\frac{∂}{dy}$ be a vector field on the plane. Compute its coordinate representation in polar coordinates on the right half-plane $\{(x,y):x>0\}$.

What I got so far:

The question asks for a coordinate representation, which can be easily obtained by composing this vector field with the map $(x,y)\to (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. So it becomes $r\cos\theta\frac{∂}{∂x}+r\sin\theta\frac{∂}{dy}$. But this is weird. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong.

Comment: hint : the thing wrong is that you did not express $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$

Comment: @user42070 would you put it into an answer? :)

Comment: @user42070 and how do I do that?

Comment: I might but basicily you just need to use chain rule. Can you by yourself ?

Comment: Like $∂/∂x=∂r/∂x\cdot ∂/∂r$?

Comment: no there is 2 variable. and  I find it less painful to in fact express the radial one in the cartesian one, then take the inverse matrix  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Comment: Hint : I think you should find $V=r\frac{\partial}{\partial_r}$ ? please post when you are done..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok since I need to go and will fell guilty if you dont find it 
We have by chain rule $$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial  r}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
which reads $$\left(\begin{array}{c} \partial_r\\ \partial_\theta\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta &\sin\theta\\ -r\sin\theta& r\cos\theta\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c} \partial_x\\ \partial_y\end{array}\right)$$
By inversing the matrix you have $$\left(\begin{array}{c} \partial_x\\ \partial_y\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta &-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta& \frac{1}{r}\cos\theta\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} \partial_r\\ \partial_\theta\end{array}\right) $$

And simple compuation give you $$V=r\partial_r$$.
When one ask you about the new coordiantes of a vector field the coordinates have to be expressed in this new local basis of the tangent space (the i.e $\partial_i$  )vector)

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thank you!

Comment: then can you mark it solved ? :)

Comment: Of course! Unfortunately I cannot upvote as I'm not registered.

Comment: For $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ are you substituting $\partial_r$

Comment: why do i get $-1$ when solving it out